# Help finishing off a cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

I'm trying to finish off a cryptic crossword. I'm down to the last four clues and I simply cannot figure them out. Can you help with the following clues? I've included the letters I have so far after the clue.

1. Bent after opening delight (7)

   > E_C_A_T
2. Kept clear of the last of the Mohicans' ground (8)

   > E_C_E_ _ _
3. Shade that may go with interior of fold (8)

   > _ _ _ _ _E_N
4. Radar device one inserted in ear turned into protection from dropping out (9)

   > _ _A_D_A_L

Additional info thanks to overlaps:

> The 7th letter of (2) is the 2nd letter of (3), and the 4th letter of (3) is is the 1st letter of (4).

A brief explanation with your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Do any of those clues overlap?

Comment: @boboquack Yes they do. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.

> `(-p)ENCHANT`

2.

> `_E + _S + CHEWED` ("chewed" as in "ground")

3.

> `PE(A GREE)N` ("fold" means "pen", as in the transitive verb meaning "to pen up")

4.

> `GU(ARDRA*)(I)L<` ("lug" is Scots for "ear")

Comment: How fast did you solve those?!

Answer (score 3):

4:

> GUARDRAIL - anagram of RADAR with I inside LUG (ear) backwards (turned) gives a protection against falling